# I just resetted my HP Pavilion Sleekbook 14 PC and the keyboard won't work

Tags: keyboard, reset

Its running Windows 10... the keyboard doesn't work. All drivers are up-to-date. Tried troubleshooting, doesn't recognize anything.

Comment: What troubleshooting did you do - with no keyboard - and what did you find out?

Comment: On screen keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm... bit of a weird way of fixing it, but here it is:

1. Boot the device; make sure the charger is not connected. Remove the battery. (Instructions should be on the back)
2. The PC will automatically shut down.
3. Plug in the charger to the PC.
4. Boot the PC.
5. Check if the keyboard works.
6. If it does, put the battery back in **without shutting down the PC**. If it doesn't, I'm sorry your out of luck.
7. Next, restart.

(Above method is suggested because I had the same problem)

Here's a few things you can do if the above method didn't work:

- Reinstall Windows
- Downgrade Windows (If you upgraded)
- Find drivers for you keyboard.
- Go to Device Manager and see if the keyboard is recognized.
- Call Windows/HP

Hope I Helped!